# Does Nuget automatically create package with PackageReference'd dependencies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a .NET 4.5.2 library using Visual Studio 2017 (v 15.9.7).

In my library project (i.e. csproj), I've added a Nuget dependency on CEFSharp for WPF (which itself includes other dependencies).

I've converted my library Nuget references to use the newer "PackageReference" mode.

When running `nuget pack` from the command line, I expect that the created `*.nupkg` would automatically include references to the CEFSharp components that my library references.

It doesn't look like this is the case. When I open the `nupkg` as a `zip`, I can't see any references to CEFSharp.

Do I really need to make my library's `nuspec` file redundantly declare the CEFSharp dependency even though my csproj already essentially defines the CEFSharp dependency?

Comment: If you're generating your nuget from a nuspec file then yes, this file must declare the dependencies to other nugets. So something like `<dependency id="CefSharp.Wpf" version="71.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're generating your nuget from a nuspec file then yes, this file must declare the dependencies to other nugets. For instance:

```
<dependencies>
  <group>
    <dependency id="CefSharp.Wpf" version="71.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```